# Short, yet powerful proofs

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question, education, irrational-numbers, big-list

One of my favorite proofs is the following:

**Claim**: There exists irrational numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha^{\beta}$ is rational.

**Proof**: Let $\alpha = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\beta = \sqrt{2}$ so $\alpha, \beta \notin \mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, $$\alpha^{\beta} = (\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}})^{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2}^{{\sqrt{2}}\cdot{\sqrt{2}}} = (\sqrt{2}^{2}) = 2 $$ So $\alpha^{\beta} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

With that said: are there are any other proofs to claims, theorems, lemma's, etc. that are short and powerful like this one? Please do share. Visual proofs are also welcome!

Comment: Don't you need to prove that $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is irrational? P.S. The question sounds too broad.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions on this site where users ask for elegant proofs of this or that result – you could search through those questions to see what people came up with, and report the results here. You could also look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26469/solutions-to-interesting-problems-with-elegant-and-unintuitive-methods which is not a thousand miles removed from the question yoou are asking here.

Comment: @A.Γ. if $\sqrt2^{\sqrt2}$ is rational, then you're already done.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson : that’s a great idea. Thank you for sharing! I thought maybe this would be a more relaxed question for users to share short proofs to good questions that stood out to them.

Comment: What do you mean elegant, what exactly does it mean? Make it short? Make it unique?

Comment: @David Morante : I see the confusion. I changed the title and body to “short, yet powerful proofs”.

Comment: IMHO the proof that the set of reals possess completeness property is a very short one (say based on  Dedekind's construction), but that forms the basis of all key theorems in analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, let $x$ be a root of the equation:
$$\left(\sqrt2\right)^x=3.$$
Prove that this $x$ is an irrational number (it's not so hard by contradiction).

Comment: @Micheal Rozenberg : Thank you for sharing! I will have to take a crack at this one.

Comment: @Taylor Rendon You are welcome!